# React Native project does not run

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I create new project in React Native and trying to run in android emulator then it returns error. Whats the problem i can't understand.[image: emulator screen]

Comment: have you moved your project from one folder to another?

Comment: try following items one by one and try to run after each step: 1. npm start, 2. npm update, 3. rm -rf node_modules 4. npm install

Comment: No its happened only when i create any new project. previously created project works successfully.

Answer (score 0):

compare your package.json file of new created project and older project. in package.json file change all react native version of new projects to older projects. then delete node_modules folder and run npm install. then run the new project. I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with latest react native version.

Create the project with below command.

```
react-native init --version="0.54.0" ProjectName
```